# Create a field that Accepts only one Password

Tags: html, passwords, user-input, post

Strange question I know, but I need to create an input field that only accepts a single password, in this case a promo code, so it can go to another page where a client can print out some pdfs and other sorts of details. Thanks for your time and let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires nothing, except that you change the code on line 6 to the PROMO you want.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
Code: <input name="code" type="text" />
<input name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_POST['code'] == "7d7cf9e1")
    {
        echo 'Code accepted.';
        //do something here
    }
    else{
        echo 'Sorry, try again.';
    }
}
?>
```

You can adapt that to your own needs.